# Firefox: Streaming video download

Tags: firefox, video, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Youtube and Google video downloaders ?](https://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders)

How can I download the streaming videos from sites like *YouTube* etc. to my PC? Should I use an addon for that?

I'm using *DownThemAll!* which is really a good download management addon, but it doesn't support streaming video downloads AFAIK.

Comment: duplicate : http://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders

Comment: @joe: I don't think so. Not exactly the same question.

Comment: Looking at the answers and reviewing both questions I do agree that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use flashgot http://flashgot.net/ or better youtube https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6460

Answer (score 2):

I use the DownloadHelper Firefox add-on.

http://www.downloadhelper.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [SaveTubeVideo](http://www.savetubevideo.com/). It cab also convert flv files to avi. You just need to have codecs for flv on your PC.